# How can I get consistent copy/paste behavior when copying data that spans hidden columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy data from selected cells, all in the same row. One of the columns in the middle of the selected range is hidden (hidden, not filtered). When I copy, the data is copied only from the visible columns. However, when the data is pasted into the hidden column. So all of the data to the right of the hidden column is shifted to the left.

Is it possible to either copy the data from the hidden column too, or not paste into the hidden column, so that the data ends up in the correct column after paste?

In the example below, the third column is hidden; I've unhidden it to show what is happening. I would like to end up with either row 3 or row 4 (either result would be ok for me). Row 1 is what I'm copying from. Row 2 is what I get after pasting.

[image]

Comment: We could copy the data from visible cells, but it seems that we could not past data into visible cells only. In my opinion, you may use formula instead. Besides, in your example, Row 4 could be achieved via normal steps of copying and pasting, as both Row 4 and Row 1 have the same hidden column.

Comment: Row 4 cannot be achieved using normal copy/paste, because since column 3 is hidden, the text copied from row1 column4 ends up in row4 column3. I don't think using a formula would be much use, since that kind of defeats the purpose of a copy/paste operation. I would never be copy/pasting from the exact same cells. Could you expand on how a formula could achieve this? Thanks,

Comment: Currently, the only way to achieve row 3 is to copy everything to the left of the hidden column, then paste. Then copy everything to the right of the hidden column, then paste. Row 4 can't be achieved without unhiding then re-hiding column 3.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. The [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE9q1.gif) shows what I said "Row 4 could be achieved via normal copy/paste". "Both" could be copied from **Row 1 Column 3** and pasted into **Row 4 Column 3**.

Comment: Ok thanks, you're right. I must have something else set up wrong with my spreadsheet that I'm not noticing then, because the behavior of the past in the gif is not what I'm getting. I just set this up from scratch in a brand new spreadsheet, and it does work how I would like it to (matching your gif).

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your method of selection might be the issue here.

The default behavior is to copy the range of selected cells, including anything hidden in the range. If you select multiple sub-ranges, copy and then paste, the paste will just be the copied cells.

For example, if I select a single range by dragging. Then Copy will copy all cells in that range, and paste will paste whatever was copied.

However, if I select the first column, then hold Ctrl and select the second column separately, then copy, then I'm not copying the hidden value because I haven't selected it. So, the paste will only paste 2 cells, which is what I've copied.

[image]

Comment: I am already clicking and dragging to select. Holding the shift key to select consecutive cells also does not work.
Though what you say is true, and may help others with a similar problem.

Comment: Shift will expand a selection range. Control will create separate selection ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry editing post as I was completely wrong.

According to what I have been able to discover all information should be copied and pasted regardless of hidden rows or columns, in each according to original row or column, depending on what is hidden and what isn't in the respective sheets, that is the default.
It is likely if this is not the behaviour that a setting has been changed.
The setting can be found in: (office 365)

Home > Find & Select, and pick Go To Special.
There is an option "Visible cells only" there.

It may also be helpful to unhide all and unfilter on both pages to work out exactly whats going on.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Go To Special will help quickly select certain classes of cells. I don't think it will change the copy/paste behavior.